# Installed Proprietary AMD Graphics Drivers from Settings, Rebooted, and Display Always Turns Off After Decrypting Partitions on Boot Screen

Tags: 13.10, software-installation, bootloader, boot-partition, gpu-driver

I did a fresh installation of Ubuntu 13.10 on my system, fiddled around a bit until I was comfortable with the system, and then went to the Settings window and elected to installed the proprietary AMD graphics drivers (`fglrx-updates`).

Following a reboot, I was only able to enter a passphrase and successfully mount my encrypted partitions before the monitor went into power-saving mode and keyboard input became unresponsive.

I need to revert the changes or at least make the installation successfully use the graphics drivers I installed.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem and the cause of it turned out to be very simple: `/boot` was not mounted when I installed the proprietary drivers!

You see, I had an encrypted installation with `/boot` residing on removable storage. Following the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1135/82847) for [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up) ([How to run scripts on start up?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/814/how-to-run-scripts-on-start-up)), I set up my system to run `umount /boot` right before the login screen and I rebooted several times to make sure this was working reliably. Then I installed the AMD proprietary graphics drivers from here:
[image: Software & Updates window]

Following the installation and reboot of the system, I ended up with no display; the monitor was in power save mode which meant the most reliable way to diagnose this problem was using something known to be working: a live Ubuntu disc and `chroot`.

Having mounted all the partitions necessary, I `chroot` into the installation and ran `apt-get remove` on every package listed by `dpkg -l '*fglrx*'`. From the output, I was able to spot that in the removal process, some files in `/boot` were being modified and `update-initramfs` was being run. Suspecting that the real problem might have been `/boot` being inaccessible during the first installation of the proprietary drivers, I ran `apt-get install fglrx-updates fglrx-amdcccle-updates` before rebooting the system.

And it worked!

Folks: make sure your `/boot` partition is available before installing or removing any software/updates! You'll never know when `/boot` might be needed.